# Excel worksheet - if the column contains X then copy the row and all rows with the same word in column A to sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

The current code copies content from sheet 1 to sheet 2 if X and from sheet 1 to sheet 3 if Y. I need it changed so that if a row in column B = X it copies every row that has the same word in Column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, cell As Range
Dim r(1 To 2) As Range
Dim v(1 To 2) As String
Dim shName(1 To 2) As String
Dim i As Long

' see below - current code copies Y rows to sheet 3
v(1) = "X"
v(2) = "Y"
shName(1) = "Sheet2"
shName(2) = "Sheet3"

'If Target.Column = 2 Then

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
Set sh2 = Worksheets(shName(i))
Set r3 = sh2.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
r3.EntireRow.Delete
Next


Set r1 = sh1.Range("B2", sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
For Each cell In r1
For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
  If UCase(cell) = UCase(v(i)) Then
     If r(i) Is Nothing Then
        Set r(i) = cell
     Else
        Set r(i) = Union(r(i), cell)
     End If
     Exit For
  End If
Next
Next


For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
 Set sh2 = Worksheets(shName(i))
 If Not r(i) Is Nothing Then
    r(i).EntireRow.Copy sh2.Rows(2)
 End If
Next

'End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by copying a row into a column ? From what I understand, I think you're overthinking this. You could use a simple Filter and then use Range.SpecialCells() and select only visible cells which will be all the rows you have filtered.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur +1, or add a column with a formula that gives NA() when the test is true, the use SpecialCells to select the cells to be copied !

Comment: So you want to copy all the `X'es` to sheet2 not regarding the `Y's`?